# How to read entire text file and print into an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a program that reads a text file which prints to the terminal and a new text file, but it reads the text file line by line. I want to edit the program so it reads the entire text file and prints the student names into an array.

Comment: Could you post the code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're currently using something similar to this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(yourFile);

while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(input.nextLine());
}
```

To put the names into an array, change it to something like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(yourFile);
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    names.add(input.nextLine());
}

String[] nameList = names.toArray();
```